# Docker mysqld bind operation not permitted

Tags: mysql, docker

Hi I have been trying to figure this out for the last month or so while trying to get my work environment to run at home.
However my database simply won’t run.
Has anyone had this problem before?
I’m running windows 10.

```
[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
[Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
[ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Operation not permitted
[ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: 
           /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: There’s not really enough information in this question to try to debug anything.  You added a “docker” tag so I’d suggest reading https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ for the official Docker MySQL image documentation, but without knowing what you’re actually doing, the error message isn’t a lot to go on.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks! Can’t believe I didn’t even read this.

Comment: @Barmar Since docker is widely used by developers, I’d say it fits fine.

Answer (score 6):

As the information say this is a permission issue,beacuse mysql doesn't have permission to create mysql.sock file.I have meet this problem too and I solved this by changing the socket path in my.cnf file: socket=/tmp/mysql.sock.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid to modify your my.cnf file, you can add the socket parameter directly in the docker run command.

That example worked for me (Windows 10) -- I have let my whole command :

```
docker run --name=mysql1 -v /code/mysql.db:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql/mysql-server --innodb_use_native_aio=0 --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```